# How to feed texts which include labeled sentences into the neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, dataset

I'm kind of new in deep learning.
I'm trying to get titles for texts.

So, for each text I have:

- Title
- Sentence
- Labels for these sentences (all are 0s and one (which is closest to the title by ROUGE1 score) is 1).
  Like `['Title'], ['s1','s2','s3','s4'], [0,1,0,0]`

I vectorized everything (titles and sentences, obviously).

The problem is I cannot wrap my head around how to feed it to the network so it would learn to predict for bunch of sentences (one text) which of the sentences would be 1 (the title).

I mean... I know when we do, for example, text classification (or sentence classification) we have the whooooole text and its label.. So we just feed to the network something like

```
x = ['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5']
y= [0,1,0,0,1]
```

But here.... we need to predict labels for each sentence in terms of 1 text.
So, I'll have something like

```
x = 
['s01','s02','s03','s04'] 
['s11','s12','s13','s14','s15','s16','s17'] 
...
['sn1','sn2','sn3']
y = 
[0,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
...
[1,0,0]
```

Plus there somewhere must be titles included.... (i think)

How would (in which form) I feed it to the network if I want to predict later for new text (let's say) `['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6']` which sentences are 0s and which is 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you have sentences in each text and to one of these sencentes you allocate the tag 'title' (or 1). 
Let us resume the problematics : in a NN you will have an input matrix, with features on columns and individuals (elements) on rows. Here, your rows are documents (title + content) and, as I see, the features are one sentence.

You will have a problem with your approach for the following reasons :

1. In your approach one feature is a sentence (I mean each sentence is more or less unique, isn't it?). Thus, you will have more features than individuals (i.e. documents, i.e. rows of your matrix), and in this case the NN provides bad results.
2. Even if you manage to get more individuals thant features, you will have a huge amount of features, which will take time and memory to train.
3. If you take into accont the words in a sentence, you risk to have titles which look like a normal sentence and here you will have ambiguity.

Why don't you try to do that with simple rules (without machine learning)? A title is generally the first sentence of a text, and shorter than the other sentences, sometimes without a verb?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I have news articles which are usually 10-20 sentences long. And about 200k articles in total. So... I think it would be manageable. I still want to try this approach. 
If I understood you correct the features would be like x0 = sentence0, x1 = sentence1, ... xN = sentenceN, right? (with no title used at all) 
How in this case would y for one row look like? Like [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]?

Comment: Indeed, and you will have to take into account all sentences for all documents. So for example if you have document d1 = [s1, s2, s3, s4] with title s2 and d2 = [s5,s6,s7], with title s5, your features will be [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7], and you may have for example: d1 = [1,2,1,1,0,0,0], with 1 for "sentence in the document" and  2 for "title of the document". But once again, the NN approache will not work, because you will have more features than documents.

Comment: If you want to use a neural network at any rate you shouldfin another dataset. Neural networks are not appropriated for your problematics and dataset.